# jQuery equivalent of document.getElementById().size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking into jQuery equivalent of following HTML DOM method in order to find size of an text box element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText">

<p>Click the button to set the width of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert(document.getElementById("myText").size);
  document.getElementById("myText").size = "50";
  alert(document.getElementById("myText").size);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Running above HTML shows two alert boxes with output 20 and 50 respectively. 20 is displayed as the default textbox size and 50 is displayed after the size is reset to 50. I need to read this size attribute through jQuery. I tried to switch following code line in above snippet with possible jQuery way but it does not shows expected output:

Current:

```
alert(document.getElementById("myText").size);
```

Changed to

```
alert($("myText").val().length);  //shows length of the value inside textbox.

alert($("myText").length); // shows 1 in the output and its expected because its jQuery's way of showing number of elements not its size.

alert($("myText").size()); // shows 1 in the output. This is equivalent to the length property. using size() is jQuery's preferred way as using length is deprecated.
```

I tried jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/size/) but could not be able to find what I am looking for. Related stackoverflow questions talk about finding length of the value inside a textbox but I am looking for the size of the textbox. My use case needs to find out size of the textbox on the UI screen in order to determine position of a tooltip box and other popup windows.

Comment: I highly doubt there are any `myText` tags in your HTML.

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById("myText").size);` Just becasue you have jquery, doesn't mean everything has to use jquery methods.

Comment: jQuery, for the most part, uses CSS selectors (with a few custom pseudo-selectors); you're searching via the `id`, so use a CSS id selector: `#myText`, and then take a read of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). It really doesn't take all that long to skim through the API and it is well-worth the short amount of time that it takes.

Comment: @AndrewLi Really!! Then what does the following code mean in my HTML?
    
    <input type="text" id="myText">

Comment: @Vishal That's an *id*, do `$("#myText")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#myText").prop("size")`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log($("#myText").prop("size"));
  $("#myText").prop("size", "50");
  console.log($("#myText").prop("size"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="myText">
<p>Click the button to set the width of the text field.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

... and use `console.log` for debugging, not `alert` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can take your old DOM. Overthwise, if you want to use CSS3 selectors, this is better

```
document.querySelector("#css3selector").size
```

And it works like the old DOM